# Neo4j RelationshipEntity and Spring JPA

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have the following nodes and relationships defined:
[CarMaker and Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8fE.png)

1. A CarModel is made CarMaker in multiple years, and that is represented as a property of the MADE_IN relationship.
2. A CarModel is made by one CarMaker only.
3. A CarMaker can make multiple CarModels in multiple years.

I have defined the following Classes to represent the nodes: CarModel, CarMaker and the relationship MADE_IN

CarModel

```
@NodeEntity
public class CarModel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Relationship (type="MADE_IN", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<MadeIn> madeIns = new HashSet<MadeIn>();
    private Set<String> years = new HashSet<String>();

    public CarModel() {     
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void addMadeIn(MadeIn madeIn) {
        System.out.println ("Found CarMaker: " + madeIn.getCarMaker());
        this.madeIns.add(madeIn);
    }

    private Set<MadeIn> getMadeIn() {
        return madeIns;     
    }

    public Set<String> getYears() {
        Iterator<MadeIn> itr = madeIns.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            years.add(((MadeIn) itr.next()).getYear());
        }

        Set<String> sortedYears = years.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        return sortedYears;
    }


}
```

CarMaker

```
public class CarMaker {

    @GraphId private Long id;
    private String name;    
    @Relationship (type="MADE_IN", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<CarModel> carModels = new HashSet<>();


    public CarMaker() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public Set<CarModel> getCarModels() {
        return carModels;
    }

    public void setCarModels(CarModel carModel) {
        carModels.add(carModel);

    }


}
```

MADE_IN

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="MADE_IN")
public class MadeIn {
    @GraphId private Long relationshipId;
    @Property private String year;
    @StartNode private CarMaker carMaker;
    @EndNode private CarModel carModel;


    public MadeIn() {

    }

    public MadeIn(CarMaker carMaker, CarModel carModel, String year) {
        this.carMaker = carMaker;
        this.carModel = carModel;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Long getRelationshipId() {
        return relationshipId;
    }

    public void setCarMaker(CarMaker carMaker) {
        this.carMaker = carMaker;
    }

    public CarMaker getCarMaker() {
        return this.getCarMaker();
    }

    public void setCarModel(CarModel carModel) {
        this.carModel = carModel;
    }

    public CarModel getCarModel() {
        return this.getCarModel();
    }


    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

When I make a request to retrieve a CarModel, I receive a response with the details of that model and all years when it was manufactured:

```
{
    "id": 260248,
    "name": "Ulysse",
    "years": [
        "1994",
        "1995",
        "1996",
        "1997",
        "1998",
        "1999",
        "2000",
        "2001",
        "2004",
        "2005",
        "2006",
        "2007",
        "2008",
        "2009",
        "2010",
        "2011",
        "2012"
    ]
}
```

The problem is when I try to request the CarModels made by a CarMaker:

{
    "id": 4152072,
    "name": "BMW",
    "carModels": []
}

I noticed that if I reverse the annotations @StartNode and @EndNode on the MadeIn class I get the information about the CarModels made by a CarMaker, however I will not longer get the information about the years when those models were made.

{
    "id": 4152072,
    "name": "BMW",
    "carModels": [
        {
            "id": 260852,
            "name": "120",
            "years": []
        },
        {
            "id": 261430,
            "name": "Z18",
            "years": []
        },
        {
            "id": 262044,
            "name": "L7",
            "years": []
        },

Any idea on what am I missing, or what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

--MD

Comment: `setCarModels` in CarMaker looks wrong, it could confuse the library. Also do you need `UNDIRECTED`? What if you use direction implied by @StartNode and @EndNode (note you also need to annotate setter on the INCOMING) side.

Comment: Got it working.  I was missing a method on the CarMaker class to keep reference to all the Models that was captured through the relationship. Thank you for your help @frant.hartm